# Tkinter GUI stopwatch/timer

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, timer

How can I make the timer to update in the `Canvas`?

In `create.text(position, **options)` the default position can be overridden with `anchor=tk.CENTER` supposedly, but I get a:

> NameError: name 'tk' is not defined

if I try to add the `anchor` option.

```
import time
from Tkinter import *

run = True; s=0; m=0; h=0

def Run():
    global run, s, m, h
    while run == True:
        time.sleep(1)
        s+=1
        if s == 59:
            m+=1; s=-1
        elif m == 59:
            h+=1; m=-1

master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=1500, height=800)
w.pack()

x.create_text(
    [750, 400], anchor=tk.CENTER, text="%s:%s:%s" % (s, m, h), font=("Consolas", 400)
    )

mainloop()

Run()
```

If I put `Run()` before `mainloop()` the Canvas doesn't start. After `mainloop()` and `Run()` doesn't start.

`mainloop(Run())` and `Run()` starts before `Canvas`.

Comment: infinite `while` loops make Tkinter lock up. Consider using `Tk.after` instead.

Comment: Also, it may be worthwhile to ask two separate questions, if you need an answer both for "why am I getting a `NameError`?" and "how do I periodically update a timer?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
from Tkinter import *
```

brings all of the names from the Tkinter library into the global namspace.  So, you can just access them directly:

```
x.create_text(
    ..., anchor=CENTER, ...
    )
```

You would only do `tk.CENTER` had you imported Tkinter like:

```
import Tkinter as tk
```

which I must say is a better approach.  It is a bad practice to clutter the global namespace by doing `from ... import *`.  Remember that:

["Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!"](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

---

Regarding the second part of your question, you cannot use `while True:` or `time.sleep` in the same thread as the Tkinter event loop is operating in.  Doing either of these will block the Tkinter loop and cause your program to freeze.

Instead, you can use [`Tk.after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) to execute `Run` in the background:

```
from Tkinter import *

run = True
s = 0
m = 0
h = 0


def Run():
    global run, s, m, h

    # Delete old text
    w.delete('all')
    # Add new text
    w.create_text(
        [750, 400], anchor=CENTER, text="%s:%s:%s" % (s, m, h), font=("Consolas", 400)
        )

    s += 1
    if s == 59:
        m += 1
        s -= 1
    elif m == 59:
        h += 1
        m -= 1

    # After 1 second, call Run again (start an infinite recursive loop)
    master.after(1000, Run)


master = Tk()
w = Canvas(master, width=1500, height=800)
w.pack()

master.after(1, Run)  # after 1 millisecond, start Run
mainloop()
```

Also, I moved the call to `Canvas.create_text` inside the `Run` function so that it is updated with each call of `Run`.  Notice too that you need to call `Canvas.delete` before you add the new text so that any old text is removed.